# FontAwesome 3.2.1 hiding anchor text values

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

How can I hide text value and just show icon at all using Font Awesome 3.2.1? The menu option needs to have a value. Here is what I have:

```
<a href="#" class="icon icon-facebook-sign">Facebook</a>
```

I tried text-indent but simply hidden the logo and not the text which was weird.

Comment: Try `<a href="#"><i class="icon icon-facebook-sign"></i></a>`

Comment: I cannot have an empty tag as cms strips it out, plus i need Facebook as the text

Comment: text-indent will hide the logo because it is text :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" class="icon icon-facebook-sign"><span class="hidden-xs">Facebook</span></a>
```

If you use Bootstrap here, you can use hidden-lg, hidden-md classes.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar way to Glyphicons (as used in Bootstrap), you can use a `span` element within the `a` tag:

```
<a href="#" title="Facebook"><span class="icon icon-facebook-sign"></span></a>
```

As advised, I have included the `title` attribute for screen readers. A screen reader should use this, as long as the `a` tag doesn't contain any text.

Comment: I would use this option, however add title="Facebook" to the anchor :)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> <span style="display:none;">Facebook</span></a>
```

This is the standard use of FontAwesome icons, that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `color:transparent` property which is very useful.

Text-indent should also work. CSS property value to `display: inline-block` or `display: block` to anchor.

One more solution is that you can put text in span tag and give span `display:none;`